# Space between wrapped elements

Tags: css

What's that white gap(space) between 2 elements and how to remove it?

P.S. 1px gap between red and black. Looks like because of 125% browser zoom.

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  display: block;
  background: black;
  height: 27px;
  width: 27px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: can you specify in detail what the gap is ?

Comment: @WilliamWang It's between red border and black span

Comment: it's really hard to find.

Comment: and if you zoom the page, the space disappears

Comment: @Eugene have you reset css yet?

Comment: OMG it is because of the browser zoom, but if zoom 100% top and left border a bit smaller than right and bottom

Comment: hmm, and if you set border to 100px then the space disappears too

Comment: @ppwater do u see top and left borders thinner than bottom and right?

Comment: Yes, if I zoom the page to 300px then I see it

Comment: @ppwater ok so the white space caused by a zoom, different thickness because of pixel resolution (I checked on higher-res display and all borders were perfect). I thought zoom is not breaking the page.

Comment: It should be a Chrome rendering issue. I have found several related problems since now, like a line in the middle of a button, without declaring any line in CSS / HTML / JS. Also, if you test your code with Firefox, in any level of zoom, you don't have this space.

Comment: @KodeFor.Me you may add this to answers and I will close the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be a Chrome rendering issue. I have found several related problems since now, like a line in the middle of a button, without declaring any line in CSS / HTML / JS. Also, if you test your code with Firefox, in any level of zoom, you don't have this space.